# What is difference between One Hot Encoding and pandas.categorical.code

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am working on some problem and have a doubt as below:

In the data set there is a text column with following unique values:

```
array(['1 bath', 'na', '1 shared bath', '1.5 baths', '1 private bath',
       '2 baths', '1.5 shared baths', '3 baths', 'Half-bath',
       '2 shared baths', '2.5 baths', '0 shared baths', '0 baths',
       '5 baths', 'Private half-bath', 'Shared half-bath', '4.5 baths',
       '5.5 baths', '2.5 shared baths', '3.5 baths', '15.5 baths',
       '6 baths', '4 baths', '3 shared baths', '4 shared baths',
       '3.5 shared baths', '6 shared baths', '6.5 shared baths',
       '6.5 baths', '4.5 shared baths', '7.5 baths', '5.5 shared baths',
       '7 baths', '8 shared baths', '5 shared baths', '8 baths',
       '10 baths', '7 shared baths'], dtype=object)
```

If I use Count Vectorize to convert them to one hot encoding,

---

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_train[colname].values)
```

---

I am getting  the below error:

---

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

---

Please let me know the cause of the error.

Instead of that Can I use :

```
pd.Categorical(_DF_LISTING_EDA.bathrooms_text).codes
```

What is the difference between One hot encoding and pd.categorical.code?

Thanks
Amit Modi

Comment: Your current code using `CountVectorizer` has nothing to do with one hot encoding. One hot encoding is also not count vectorizing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to conver this categroical data for One hot encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) is not One hot encoding
- [Pandas Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Categorical.codes.html) is not One hot encoding

if you want One hot encoding using pandas you can do :

```
pandas.get_dummies(X_train[colname])[0]
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am have gone through the documentaion of one hot encoder in Sk-Learn. In one ho encoder we  split our data set for test train and train One hot encoder on train data and get output from test data. in this way it can handle un seen data, Can pandas.get_dummies handle un seen data too?

Comment: No, you need to do extra work for that ,like making some dict of encoded train variables and if new variable is not there u add it as "other"